# convert list of pandas dictionaries sharing the same key in a unique dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
dict_list = [{'A': [1,2],
              'B': [3,4],
              'C': [5,6]},
             {'A': [7,8],
              'B': [9,10],
              'C': [11,12]}]
```

Which keys are 'A','B','C' (key names are just an example) for all the dictionaries (here 2, but they are many more...always with the same keys)

How can I convert this list of dictionaries into a unique dictionary like below?

```
dict_list2 = {'A': np.array([[1,2],[7,8]]),
              'B': np.array([[3,4],[9,10]]),
              'C': np.array([[5,6],[11,12]])}
```

Comment: with a `for`-loop?!

Comment: No with dictionary comprehension.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that every key occurs in every dictionary? Or is it possible that `'A'` is not part of some dictionaries?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem and a dictionary comprehension is not a loop?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes

Comment: @MatthiasBurger: not in the strict sense. Since it has special grammar that is interpreted at interpreted level :p Of course behind the curtains, looping is done. In lazy functional languages it is even not a loop at all, since generation is postponed.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem interesting.. didn't work with python since 2 years anymore :( - thx for explaining.

Comment: Isn't your desired output exactly the same as if you'd just pass the list as the data arg to `DataFrame` ctor: `pd.DataFrame(dict_list)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *dictionary comprehension* for that:

```
import numpy as np

dict_list2 = {k:np.array([d[k] for d in dict_list]) for k in dict_list[0]}
```

We make the assumption that `dict_list` **contains at least one dictionary**, and that all keys of that dictionary **are repeated in the dictionaries**. In other words if `dict_list[0]` contains `'A'`, we assume all the dictionaries contain an `'A'` key. Which seems a reasonable assumption.

This gives:

```
>>> dict_list2
{'C': array([[ 5,  6],
       [11, 12]]), 'A': array([[1, 2],
       [7, 8]]), 'B': array([[ 3,  4],
       [ 9, 10]])}
```

The fact that the formatting is not very elegantly, is because `numpy` formats matrices with new lines, but you can see the content is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas solution - use [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor and [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
print (pd.DataFrame(dict_list).to_dict(orient='list'))
{'A': [[1, 2], [7, 8]], 'B': [[3, 4], [9, 10]], 'C': [[5, 6], [11, 12]]}
```

But if need numpy arrays, add `dictionary comprehension`:

```
print ({k: np.array(v) for k, v in pd.DataFrame(dict_list).to_dict(orient='list').items()})
{'A': array([[1, 2],
       [7, 8]]), 'B': array([[ 3,  4],
       [ 9, 10]]), 'C': array([[ 5,  6],
       [11, 12]])}
```